# shell スクリプトの if 文の条件内で、バッククォートによるコマンド置換がしたい

Tags: linux, sh

sh のコードを短くしたいです。

```
RES=`service httpd status`
if [ "$RES" = 'httpd is stopped' ]; then
  echo "stopped"
fi
```

↓ 以下のように

```
if [ `service httpd status` = 'httpd is stopped' ]; then
  echo "stopped"
fi
```

ただ、`service httpd status`の書き方がまずいみたいで、*too many arguments*
と出てしまいます。
どのように記述すればいいでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 後から検索する人にも、タイトルだけで内容がわかりやすいよう編集してみました。ずれてるところなどあれば、お手数ですが[edit]して上書きしてしまってください。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

提示されたコードですと、
`service httpd status` の実行結果による置き換えで

```
if [ httpd start/running, process XXXX = 'httpd is stopped' ]; then
  echo "stopped"
fi
```

のようになってしまうのが原因だと思われます。
ダブルクオートで囲って

```
if [ "`service httpd status`" = 'httpd is stopped' ]; then
  echo "stopped"
fi
```

とすれば大丈夫でしょう。

Comment: なるほど。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

sh -xv に渡してみるとエラーが発生している箇所が良く分かります。

```
[shige@mcc ~]$ sh -xv test.sh
RES=`/sbin/service httpd status`
/sbin/service httpd status
++ /sbin/service httpd status
+ RES='httpd is stopped'
if [ "$RES" = 'httpd is stopped' ]; then
  echo "stopped"
fi
+ '[' 'httpd is stopped' = 'httpd is stopped' ']'
+ echo stopped
stopped

[shige@mcc ~]$ sh -xv test2.sh
if [ `/sbin/service httpd status` = 'httpd is stopped' ]; then
  echo "stopped"
fi
/sbin/service httpd status
++ /sbin/service httpd status
+ '[' httpd is stopped = 'httpd is stopped' ']'
test2.sh: line 1: [: too many arguments
```

'httpd is stopped'
と
httpd is stopped
のように、まとまった文字列として処理されていないのが分かると思います。

対策は既に回答頂いている方の方法をご参照ください。

Comment: そんな見方があったのですね。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

そもそもなところですが、真っ当な lsb のスクリプトならサービスの状態は `service httpd status` の終了コードで判別できるのではないでしょうか？

0 なら実行中で、3 なら停止中です。

```
service httpd status 1>/dev/null 2>&1
case $? in
  0)
    echo "started"
    ;;
  3)
    echo "stopped"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "unknown"
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

おそらくお節介ですがこんな書き方もあります。

```
service httpd status | grep -q 'httpd is stopped' && echo stopped
```

ご参考まで。